# Ajax modal not opening after filtering the categories

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a modal which pops up when post is clicked to show the content inside of it. It all works fine on the frontpage but also on right side I got sidebar with all listed categories that is also working with ajax call to filter out posts based on clicked category.

Now whenever the visitor clicks category on the sidebar content on the frontpage gets updated with the new posts associated with that category which is OK. But if I try to click on the post that modal which works fine to show content on the front-page is not working somehow? What might be the issue here?

button I'm using to fire ajax

```
 <a href="#" type="button" class="view-post" data-postid="<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-slug="<?php echo get_post_field('post_name', $post_id); ?>"></a>
```

**modal-ajax.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.view-post').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var postID = $(this).data('postid');
        var postSlug = $(this).data('slug');

        // changing URL based on the post slug
        window.history.pushState(null, null, postSlug);

        $.ajax({
            url: wpAjax.ajaxUrl, // WordPress AJAX endpoint
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action: 'get_post_content',
                post_id: postID,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#modal-content-placeholder').html(response);
                $('#modal').show();
            }
        });
    });

    $('.homeInner').click(function() {
        $('#modal').hide();
    });

    $(window).click(function(event) {
        if (event.target == $('#modal')[0]) {
            $('#modal').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

**modal-callback.php**

```
<?php 

function get_post_content() {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $post_slug = $_POST['post_slug'];

    $args = array(
        'p' => $post_id,
        'post_type' => 'post',
    );

    $singlePostQuery = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($singlePostQuery->have_posts()) {
        while ($singlePostQuery->have_posts()) {
            $singlePostQuery->the_post();
            // Display the post content here
            the_content();
        }
    } else {
        // No posts found
        echo 'No posts found';
    }


    wp_die();

}
add_action('wp_ajax_get_post_content', 'get_post_content');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_post_content', 'get_post_content');
```

Ajax file and callback function for filtering in sidebar I'm using

**filter-ajax.js**

```
(function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.js-filter-item', function(event){
            (event).preventDefault();

            var category = $(this).data('category');
            var categorySlug = $(this).data('slug');

            // changing URL based on the category slug
            window.history.pushState(null, null, categorySlug);

            $.ajax({
                url: wpAjax.ajaxUrl,
                data: { 
                    action: 'filterterm', 
                    category: category, 
                    taxonomy:  $(this).data('taxonomy'),
                    posttype:  $(this).data('posttype')
                    },
                type: 'post',
                success: function(result){
                    $('#response').html(result);
                },
                error: function(result){
                    console.warn(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**ajax-callback.php**

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filterterm', 'filter_ajax_term');
add_action('wp_ajax_filterterm', 'filter_ajax_term');

function filter_ajax_term(){

    $category = $_POST['category'];

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $_POST['post'], 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'orderby'   => 'NAME', 
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    if ($category !== null && isset($category) && $category !== '' && !empty($category)) {
        $args['tax_query'] = 
            array( 
                array( 
                        'taxonomy' => $_POST['taxonomy'], 
                        'field' => 'id', 
                        'terms' => array((int)$category) 
                    ) 
            ); 
    } else {
        $all_terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'acquisition', 'fields' => 'slugs'));
        $args['tax_query'][] = [
            'taxonomy' => 'acquisition',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $all_terms
        ];
    }


    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    
    <div class="blogPostsWrapper mt-10">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 mr-5">

            <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'partials/blog', 'card' ); ?>
        
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php

    die();
}

?>
```

**blog-card.php**

```
<div class="blogCardBlackOverlay">
    <div class="col-span-1 shadow-2xl">
    <?php $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>
        <div class="relative blogPostCard rounded-2xl" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,47,75,0.5) 0%, rgba(220, 66, 37, 0.3) 130%), url('<?php echo $thumb;?>')">
            <h1 class="blogPostCard_title font-sans text-white font-bold text-start"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <!-- Gettng custom taxonomies associate with teh post -->
            <?php
                $post_id = get_the_ID();
                $terms = get_the_terms($post_id, 'acquisition');

                if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
                    $first_term = reset($terms); ?>
                    <span class="blogCard_taxonomy__item py-1 px-4 text-sm rounded-2xl absolute bottom-4 right-4 font-medium item-<?php echo $first_term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $first_term->name; ?></span>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            <!-- Reading time -->
            <div class="blogPost_readingTime__wrapper">
                <?php 
                $readingTime = get_field('reading_time');
                ?>
                <div class="blogPost_readingTime text-white text-avenir absolute bottom-4 left-4">
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-lightbulb"></i>
                    <span><?php echo $readingTime; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
                <a href="#" type="button" class="view-post" data-postid="<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-slug="<?php echo get_post_field('post_name', $post_id); ?>"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not triggered? Have you checked the network tab of your browser?

Comment: @LajosArpad I'm pretty sure it's not triggering because when I click on the button # which is in href gets added to the url which doesn't happen on the front page on which modal pops up with the content.

Comment: I would like to kindly ask you to double-check nevertheless, just to be absolutely sure.

Comment: @LajosArpad just checked, network tab is empty which is not the case on front page where modal is working fine

Comment: Thanks. So, if you add an `alert(1)` just after your `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` line, do you see a 1 when you load the front page and do you see it when you load the other page?

Comment: @LajosArpad added alert as suggested, it pops up on front page but not when I filter out posts... just like modal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255867/discussion-between-cobnetcknn-and-lajos-arpad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, so this is solution

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

on method should be used

```
$(document).on('click', '.view-post', function(e){
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be (based on the discussion we had about the question) that the

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.view-post').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var postID = $(this).data('postid');
        var postSlug = $(this).data('slug');

        // changing URL based on the post slug
        window.history.pushState(null, null, postSlug);

        $.ajax({
            url: wpAjax.ajaxUrl, // WordPress AJAX endpoint
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action: 'get_post_content',
                post_id: postID,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#modal-content-placeholder').html(response);
                $('#modal').show();
            }
        });
    });

    $('.homeInner').click(function() {
        $('#modal').hide();
    });

    $(window).click(function(event) {
        if (event.target == $('#modal')[0]) {
            $('#modal').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

script is being added to the front page, but not the other page. You will need to make sure that you properly add the script that is supposed to trigger the event when the anchor is being clicked.

Comment: everything is happening on the front page, no new page is loaded when category is clicked it's also done through ajax. It's just that modal doesn't pop up when posts are filtered through categories in the sidebar for some reason.

Comment: @COBNETCKNN Is the page reloaded when you click on a side menu?

Comment: nope, as I said filtering through categories is also done through ajax so no new page is being loaded... modal pops up fine on front page, but when I use category filters in sidebar and they show new posts suddenly modal doesn't work on posts shown

Comment: @COBNETCKNN is your structure rewritten with the AJAX callback? Because if so, the event handlers are destroyed

Comment: Updated the post with ajax files for filtering... it's returning same handlers as on the frontpage.. Classname is the same and I'm getting data-postid in anchor tag just like on front page but it's just not triggering for some reason

Comment: @COBNETCKNN do you have an item of `js-filter-item`? Why do you have a ready event or so at an AJAX callback? If you could create a Fiddle or a snippet that reproduces your problem, it would be great. Otherwise there will be many questions to be answered before we reach the solution.

Comment: I can push everything to staging domain and give you link to github repo if that would help?

Comment: @COBNETCKNN that would be great, but I cannot promise to look into the details quickly, but will try to do so as early as possible.